# Prove that the function can be rewritten as follows

Tags: calculus

Prove that the function $f(x)=((x^3)(x^2+x-2))/((x-1)(x^3+5x^2+6x))$ can be written as: $f(x)=x^2/3 + A(x)$, where $A(x)$ is a function with the property $\lim_{x\to 0} ((A(x)/x^2))=0$.

Translated from my native language, so it might be incorrectly formulated. This is what I've managed thus far:

$((x^3)(x^2+x-2))/((x-1)(x^3+5x^2+6x)) - x^2/3 = A(x)$

$-x^3/3(x+3) = A(x)$

At this point I'm stuck, and I'm pretty sure what I've done up to this point is incorrect. Any tips?

Could I just multiply by $x^2$ so that $\lim_{x\to 0}A(x) =x^5/3(x+3)$?

Comment: Hard to read.  Please edit your question, using [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to display the math.

Comment: "*pretty sure what I've done up to this point is incorrect*" $\;-\;$ Why? What's missing is to prove that $\, \lim_{x \to 0} A(x)/x^2=0\,$.

Answer (score 1):

> Prove that the function

> $$f(x) = \frac{\left(x^3\right)\left(x^2 + x − 2\right)}
> {(x − 1) \left(x^3 + 5x^2 + 6x\right)}$$

> can be written as: $$f(x) = \frac{x^2}{3} + A(x),$$

> where A(x) is a function with the property

> $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{A(x)}{x^2} = 0.\tag1 $$

In my opinion, the easiest approach is to re-express $f(x)$ as

$$f(x) = \frac{N\text{(umerator)}}{D\text{(enominator)}},\tag2 $$

eliminate common factors from $N$ and $D$,

form the function $\displaystyle g(x) = \left[\frac{N}{D} - \frac{x^2}{3}\right] \times \left[\frac{1}{x^2}\right]$

and then show that
$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} g(x) = 0.$

Based on (2) above,

$$N = \left(x^3\right)\left(x^2 + x − 2\right) = \left(x^3\right)
(x - 1)(x + 2). \tag3 $$

$$D = (x − 1) \left(x^3 + 5x^2 + 6x\right) = (x - 1)(x)(x + 3)(x + 2).\tag4$$

Examination of (3) and (4) show that $N$ and $D$ share 
the common factors : $(x)(x-1)(x+2)$.

---

**Edit**

In light of the overall assertion that must be proven, the fact that $f(x)$ is undefined for any $x \in \{1,0,-3,-2\}$ is irrelevant.  That is, when examining the limit of an expression, as $x$ goes to $0$, the specific value of the expression at
$(x = 0)$ is excluded from  consideration.

---

Therefore, $f(x)$ may be re-expressed as

$$f(x) = \frac{N}{D} = \frac{x^2}{x + 3}.$$

This implies that

$$g(x) = \left[f(x) - \frac{x^2}{3}\right] \times \left[\frac{1}{x^2}\right] = \left[\frac{x^2}{x + 3} - \frac{x^2}{3}\right] \times \left[\frac{1}{x^2}\right].$$

$g(x)$ simplifies to

$$g(x) = \left[\frac{1}{x + 3} - \frac{1}{3}\right] = 
\left[\frac{3 - (x + 3)}{3(x + 3)}\right] = \left[\frac{-x}{3x + 9}\right].\tag5 $$

At this point, it only remains to demonstrate that the RHS expression in
(5) above goes to $(0)$ as $x$ goes to $(0)$.  How this should be done depends on what theory around limits that you have been taught.

---

The easy way is to assume that if you have **continuous functions** $h(x), j(x)$ where $j(0) \neq 0$, then the

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{h(x)}{j(x)} = \frac{h(0)}{j(0)}. \tag6 $$

Using the approach in (6) above, the evaluation of the limit, as $x \to (0)$ of the RHS of (5) above is

$$\frac{0}{9} = 0.$$

---

The remainder of this posting, which you may wish to skip, is a more basic (and more convoluted) $\epsilon, \delta$ demonstration that

$$\lim_{x \to 0} ~~\frac{-x}{3x + 9} = 0$$

What must be shown is that

$$\forall ~\epsilon > 0, ~\exists ~\delta > 0, ~~\text{such that} $$

$$\left\{ ~0 < |x - 0| < \delta ~\right\}  ~~\implies ~~
\left\{ ~\left| ~\frac{-x}{3x + 9} - 0 ~\right| < \epsilon ~\right\}. \tag7 $$

The premise in (7) above may be equivalently re-expressed as

$$ - \delta < x < \delta ~~\text{and}~~ x \neq 0, \tag8 $$

while the conclusion in (7) above may be equivalently expressed as

$$ - \epsilon < \frac{-x}{3x + 9} < \epsilon. \tag9 $$

---

Therefore, the problem has been reduced to demonstrating that a relationship between $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ may be established so that if
(8) above is true, then (9) above will also be true.

Using (8) above as a premise, you have that

$$-3\delta < 3x < 3\delta \implies -3\delta + 9 < (3x + 9) < 3\delta + 9. \tag{10}$$

At this point, it becomes convenient to add an artificial constraint on $\delta$.  $\delta$ will be required to always be $\leq 1$.

This allows you to re-write (10) above as

$$(6) \leq (-3\delta + 9) < (3x + 9) < (3\delta + 9) \leq (12). \tag{11}$$

Using the conclusion in (11), the minimum and maximum possible values for the fraction in (9) can be determined analytically, in terms of $\delta$.

The fraction to be analyzed is $\displaystyle \frac{-x}{3x + 9}.$

A lower bound for the numerator is $- \delta$.  Since this lower bound is negative, the overall lowest bound is achieved by minimizing the value of the denominator.  The lower bound for the denominator is $(6)$.

Therefore, you can conclude that
$$\frac{-\delta}{6} < \frac{-x}{3x + 9}.\tag{12} $$

In a similar fashion, you can conclude that
$$\frac{-x}{3x + 9} < \frac{\delta}{6}. \tag{13}$$

What has been determined is that if the premise in (8) above holds, and if the added constraint that $\delta \leq 1$ is given, then you can conclude that the results in (12) and (13) both hold.  That is:

$$\frac{-\delta}{6} < \frac{-x}{3x + 9} < \frac{\delta}{6}. \tag{14}$$

Since (14) above is implied, and (9) above is the **desired implication**,
$\delta$ may be specified so that $\delta \leq 6\epsilon.$

Putting this together with the constraint that $\delta \leq 1$ gives a final specification of

$$\delta = \min\left(6\epsilon, 1\right).$$

Answer (score 0):

Expanding it out,
$f(x)
=\dfrac{x^5+x^4-2x^3}{x^4 + 4 x^3 + x^2 - 6 x}
$.

In general,
if
$f(x)
=\dfrac{ax^n+p(x)}{bx^m+q(x)}
$
where
$a\ne 0, b\ne 0$,
$\deg(p)\le n-1,
\deg(q)\le m-1
$
($\deg{g}$
is the degree of $g$)
then

$\begin{array}\\
f(x)-\dfrac{a}{b}x^{n-m}
&=\dfrac{ax^n+p(x)}{bx^m+q(x)}-\dfrac{ax^n}{bx^m}\\
&=\dfrac{abx^{n+m}+bx^mp(x)-abx^{n+m}-ax^nq(x)}{bx^m+q(x)}\\
&=\dfrac{bx^mp(x)-ax^nq(x)}{bx^m(bx^m+q(x))}\\
\end{array}
$

Since
$\deg(bx^mp(x))
\le n+m-1$
and
$\deg(bx^nq(x))
\le n+m-1$,
$\deg(bx^mp(x)-ax^nq(x))
\le n+m-1
$
so
$f(x)-\dfrac{a}{b}x^{n-m}
$
is of order
$x^{(n+m-1)-(2m)}
$
or
$x^{n-m-1}
$.